# How to test express rendering with supertest and mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I wanted to start testing express routes today but I can figure out how to test rendering jade views.

Here is my code:

Route:

```
  router.get('/', function(req: any, res: any) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  });
```

Test:

```
 describe('GET / ', () => {
   it('renders index', (done) => {
     request(router)
       .get('/')
       .render('index', { title: 'Express' })
       .expect(200, done);
   });
 });
```

Of course `.render` causes an error. How should I test rendering?

Comment: Check if the outcome of the request matches what should have been rendered?

Answer (score -1):

You might need to configure the rendering engine in your test. Check the response `body` for something like `Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`.

I was able to use:

```
// Setup Fake rendering
beforeEach(() => {
  app.set('views', '/path/to/your/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ext');
  app.engine('ext', (path, options, callback) => {
    const details = Object.assign({ path, }, options);
    callback(null, JSON.stringify(details));
  });
}

it('your awesome test', async () => {
  const res = await agent.get('/route').type('text/html');

  // This will have your response as json
  expect(res.text).to.be.defined;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [chai](http://aaronsofaly.github.io/chai-docs/) instead

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiHttp);

    describe('Route Index', () => {
        it('should render the index view with title', (done) => {
            chai.request(app)
                .get('/')
                .end((err, res) => {
                    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                    expect(res).to.have.header('content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
                    expect(res.text).to.contain('Express');
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is `app` here simply a new express instance, like at the top of the test file `const app = new express()`?